# Playing 2 videos in a loop

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, video

So I have already accomplished the task of making sure that a certain mp4 downloaded video runs in a loop in an application in android studio. I want to add another downloaded mp4 video on the same activity screen so that the two videos run in a loop continuously but I cannot figure out how to implement it.

Here is my xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String fileName = "video";
    String filePlace = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + fileName;

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePlace));

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    videoView.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Exoplayer library to play the videoes. In it, there is a class called ConcatenatingMediaSource in which multiple media sources can be appended.

Looping indefinitely can also be accomplished easily by ExoPlayer.setRepeatMode.